# Picture looking sharp in Live View mode, then losing sharpness after picture has being taken

Tags: canon, macro, sharpness, live-view

Since recently I am experiencing an issue with the sharpness of my images.

I am using canon 70D with a macro lens for shooting jewellery and I need to have a very clear picture to capture the brilliance of the crystals. That's why I am using a tripod, I am using tethering between computer and camera and I shoot from the software program basically - my camera is as still as it gets when taking a photo.

What happens is that the crystals of the jewellery look sharp when I am looking at Live View mode and then when I look at the picture after it has been shot sharpness is lost to a certain extend.

This is how the image looks before taking the picture (in live view mode):
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHYrS.jpg

This is how it looks afterwards:

[image]

https://i.imgur.com/xubtioq

I took these pictures with my smartphone capturing the screen of the camera. If you look closely you will see the difference. It won't be noticeable in daily life pictures I suppose, but for my job, it is an issue.

Does anybody have an idea what is the problem here ? I recently upgraded the firmware to 1.1.3 (canon 70D), of course, that shouldn't be an issue, but I figured I will mention it.

Thank you!

Comment: Another one! See [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/122093/11772) for advice and answers...

Comment: Or to follow up from Bob T's comment: if that linked question _doesn't_ answer your question, please edit your question to explain what more information you need. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the model of the lens and the camera settings (Imgur clear them from images)

Comment: This one does actually look out of focus, as opposed to yesterday's. First suspect would be autofocus "changing its mind" as the focus point seems to have moved backwards; but as Romeo says, we need details of how it was taken. Also, both images are a picture of the Live View screen. It would be far better to have the actual resulting shot for comparison.

Comment: What lens and F-Stop?  Manual or auto focus?

Comment: Are you using manual focus? If not, try that and see if things improve. Manual focus, when shooting macro, allows you to focus on the plane you want.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how live-view is handled, the aperture and speed for live-view can be different than your actual settings for snapping the photo. This can cause the DOF to be deeper during live view than the exposure, and the speed could be faster for livevew than your exposure where you may be getting blur.

The exposure is what matters anyhow. Always check your shots to understand how the DOF is and if it is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

**RAW Format**

You don't write, if you are taking the photos in RAW format, however, this might be the source of the problem.

If you take photographs in RAW, you are presented with a preview of the RAW rendered as jpg in-camera. This jpg is usually already processed and sharpened.

To get to the same level, you will have to process your RAW files, which includes some enhancing of contrast and sharpness.

**LCD Screen Size**

The small size of the lcd screen als makes pictures appear sharper than it really is. You have the same effect with images in photoshop - you can downsample a moderately sharp image and resharpen into something smaller that appears to be tack-sharp. Or you can zoom into an image with good sharpness to a point where it no longer appears very sharp.

Comment: I am not taking the photos in RAW format. It's not that which is the problem, because I have been doing it like this for years. Only in the past few days something changed. But it is not because of the RAW format, the exp., aperture or ISO.

The image is in focus, looks sharp and then I push the trigger and bam - the result is I have not so sharped image. I have never had that happen. What was on the screen was also shown in the end result of the picture.

Sharp image (it was shot when the camera was working fine):
https://imgur.com/Uvf5oEJ

Not sharp image:
https://imgur.com/yrlxflL

Comment: The new image looks just a bit out of focus. Can you give us the complete exposure data of both? shutterspeed and aperture?